# Show div based on variable (t/f) jade

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, iframe, pug

I'm trying to check whether a page is in an iframe, and show divs accordingly.

In the page I have:

```
script.
  var iframeCheck = (self !== top);
  console.log(iframeCheck);
```

So far, when I load the page (not in an iframe), it logs "false" and when I'm loading the page in an iframe, it logs "true".

Where I'm running into trouble:

In my html (jade), I have the condition:

```
if iframeCheck
  a.button#showIfIframeOnly(href="") Show if iFrame only
else
  a.button#showIfNotIframeOnly(href="") Show if not in iFrame
```

It is showing the 'else' portion in both instances (page in iFrame and page not in iFrame).

I understand I'm probably syntaxing it wrong, but the Jade docs suck for this.

Why is it logging correctly, but displaying the wrong div?

Comment: You can't assign a variable from a script to a pug variable that is used before the variable has been set.

Comment: You will need to create both elements regardless of `iframeCheck`, then show/hide it after the page has rendered.

Comment: Ah yes, I was hoping there would be a better way than this. Thank you!